# Network Error on posting form with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am new Developer **ReactJS**, I develop a registration form with **ReactJS** on FrontEnd, **NodeJS** on BackEnd and **MySQL** about the database.

I want to submit register form, when, I test my Backend on Postman, it works well and insert a date on my database such as I get: `{ "code": 200, "success": "user registered sucessfully" }`

My code is below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import AppBar from 'material-ui/AppBar';
import RaisedButton from 'material-ui/RaisedButton';
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';
import axios from 'axios';
import Login from './Login';

class Register extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            email: '',
            password: ''
        }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        console.log("nextProps", nextProps);
    }
    handleClick(event, role) {
        var apiBaseUrl = "http://localhost:4000/api";


        if (this.state.username.length > 0 && this.state.email.length > 0 && this.state.password.length > 8) {
            var payload = {
                "username": this.state.username,

                "email": this.state.email,
                "password": this.state.password
            }
            axios.post(apiBaseUrl + '/register', payload)
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    if (response.data.code === 200) {
                        console.log("registration successfull");
                    }
                    else {
                        console.log("some error ocurred", response.data.code);
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }
        else {
            alert("Input field value is missing");
        }

    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
        <MuiThemeProvider>
          <div>
          <AppBar
             title="Register"
           />
           <TextField
             hintText="Enter votre username"
             floatingLabelText="Username"
             onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({username:newValue})}
             />
           <br/>

           <TextField
           type = "email"
             hintText="Email"
             floatingLabelText="Email"
             onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({email:newValue})}
             />
           <br/>
           <TextField
             type = "password"
             hintText="Enter your Password"
             floatingLabelText="Password"
             onChange = {(event,newValue) => this.setState({password:newValue})}
             />
           <br/>
           <RaisedButton label="Submit" primary={true} style={style} onClick={(event) => this.handleClick(event)}/>
          </div>
         </MuiThemeProvider>
      </div>
        );
    }
}

const style = {
    margin: 15,
};

export default Register;
```

My package.json is :

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "0.8.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.15.3",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.0",
    "react": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
    "react-dropzone": "^3.10.0",
    "react-file-tree": "0.0.8",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.0.0",

  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:4000/"
}
```

When I run my frontend, I get :

```
xhr.js:175 OPTIONS http://localhost:4000/api//register 0 ()
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:175
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:12
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:52
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:57
Axios.(anonymous function) @ Axios.js:77
wrap @ bind.js:9
handleClick @ Register.js:33
onClick @ Register.js:93
EnhancedButton._this.handleClick @ EnhancedButton.js:146
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:542
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:581
invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:438
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ react-dom.development.js:452
executeDispatch @ react-dom.development.js:836
executeDispatchesInOrder @ react-dom.development.js:858
executeDispatchesAndRelease @ react-dom.development.js:956
executeDispatchesAndReleaseTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:967
forEachAccumulated @ react-dom.development.js:935
processEventQueue @ react-dom.development.js:1112
runEventQueueInBatch @ react-dom.development.js:3607
handleTopLevel @ react-dom.development.js:3616
handleTopLevelImpl @ react-dom.development.js:3347
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:11082
batchedUpdates @ react-dom.development.js:2330
dispatchEvent @ react-dom.development.js:3421

Register.js:53 Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:87)
```

How can I fix it please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure, but the way you defined the apiBaseUrl is not correct I guess. Please have a look at it.

Comment: Yes, it's right, `axios ('/api/register/')` that works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned - if your backend is on a different port or URL, remember to turn on CORS:

```
axios.post(apiBaseUrl + '/register', payload, { withCredentials: true })
```

Also please check what content are you expecting on the server side - by default `axios.post` will send the data as JSON (with `Content-Type` header set to `application/json`), if you're expecting it to be let's say `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` then set the `Content-Type` header accordingly.

```
axios.post(apiBaseUrl + '/register', payload, {
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running frontend in a different port, CORS may be the reason. Backend doesn't allow requests coming from frontends which run in a different server or port. To avoid this, you can add this code to your frontend: (Better to include in app.js file to make sure it will work in all scripts)

```
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Also, you need to add the following code to your NodeJS backend: (Better to include in server.js) (I suppose that you use express framework)

```
var app = express();
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:YOUR_FRONT_END_PORT');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', ['PATCH', 'POST', 'GET', 'DELETE', 'PUT']);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', ['Content-Type']);
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Expose-Headers', ['Content-Type']);
  next();
});
```

You may need the following code as well if you use any custom middleware. In your middleware add:

```
if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
  return next();
}
```

But if you do not know what you are doing with these exceptions, please consider using a web server like NGINX in the future.